# odd value of "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo, this

In the code below this gets as value [function()] according to firebug, instead of the object returned by the define.

---

```
define(["dojo/dom", 
        "dojo/dom-construct", 
                ......., 
        "dojo/domReady!"], 

function(dom, 
         construct, 
         ........){ 

    return { 

        is_empty_attr: function(attr){ 
            if (attr.many){ 
                return attr.peeks.length === 0; 
            } else { 
                return !attr.peeks; 
            } 
        }, 
                ................ 

        add_button: function(attr){ 
            console.log(this); <- 1
            var self = this; 
            return new Button({ 
                label: 'add', 
                showLabel: false, 
                iconClass: "add_icon", 
                disabled: this.is_empty_attr(attr), <- 2
                onClick: function(){ 
                    if (attr.inline){ 
                        ajax.newObject(self.sub_path_func(attr), function(json){ 
                            self.object_table(json, "val_"+attr.path); 
                        }); 
                    } else { 
                        ajax.newObject(self.sub_path_func(attr), function(json){ 
                            self.object_dialog(json); 
                        }); 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 
        }, 

    };     
});
```

---

line (<-1) logs "[function()]" 
line (<-2) therefore gives an undefined function error.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

[edit] I've solved the problem (by guesswork), but in the original version i passed the array [this.add_button, this.someotherbutton] to another function which called each function in the array with the attr argument. All methods are part of the same returned object of the dojo define method. It worked after i passed [this.add_button(attr), this.someotherbutton(attr)] (so the actual buttons) as argument to the second function.

I still don't understand how that changed the "this" value in add_button, since both methods where add_button was called seem comparable, so if someone could explain i would be grateful.[end edit]

Cheers, Lars

Comment: It would help to see an example of where `add_button` is called, since `this` in JavaScript is bound at the time of the method call.

Comment: I'll edit some more info in.

Answer (score 1):

Use [dojo/_base/declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare) to define your class :

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/dom", 
        "dojo/dom-construct", 
            ......., 
        "dojo/domReady!"], 

function(declare,
         dom, 
         construct, 
         ........){ 

    return declare([], {
        is_empty_attr: function(attr){ 
            ...
        },
        add_button: function(attr){
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sry, thanks, does this restrict the "this" reference to the module for all (non nested/non callback) functions in the module?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use lang.hitch from the dojo/_base/lang package to change the execution scope of any function. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch